# How to describe sand flowing through an hourglass

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, poetic

I'm thinking of somewhat of a poetic way to describe how time flows, via an hourglass. Does sand simply 'flow' through an hourglass?

Drip doesn't sound applicable, and 'stream' is basically like flow; while shifting feels more applicable to an outdoor scenario (like a desert).

Basically, what's another applicable word, or perhaps phrasing, to describe sand moving through an hourglass?

Comment: ***Trickle***:  To flow or fall in drops or in a thin stream.

Comment: Flow seems fine to me; why is it wrong for you? As far as I understand it, sand definitely flows.

Comment: Like sands through the hourglass, so are the days of our lives. [[[Sorry!]]]

Comment: 'Run' and 'drop' are common collocates; those would give you the cliched 'poetic' tone. Depending on context, 'flush' might be appropriate.

Comment: Many people have now given suggestions in answer to your question. But if you are striving for "poetry", you might also want to improve on *thinking of somewhat of a poetic way*. It is not really grammatical.

Comment: 'How about 'drops'? *Sand drops through the hourglass like a bad thief through the hangman's trap* :D

Comment: Perhaps "time is running out" (*used to say that there is not much time left in which to achieve something*):

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Flow is fine, but just looking for alternatives that fit into what I want to write.

Answer (score 23):

There's always the famous (and parodied) introduction to the soap opera *The Days of Our Lives*:

> "Like sand **through** the hour glass, so are the days of our lives."

The usages that the Ngram viewer finds:

From [*The Hourglass of My Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0LiFCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT119&dq=%22sand%20running%20through%20an%20hourglass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0iof6mdfPAhUI7iYKHUFID9MQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22sand%20running%20through%20an%20hourglass%22&f=false) by Caite Grace:

> Like sand **running** through an hourglass, I can see my life slipping away in front of me

From [*Treating Addicted Survivors of Trauma*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ucby7SldCvYC&pg=PA254&dq=sand%20running%20through%20an%20hourglass&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh4qObm9fPAhWDSiYKHa0UDmwQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=sand%20running%20through%20an%20hourglass&f=false) by K Evans and J. M Sullivan:

> The dragon is lying on sand, with more sand **flowing** through an
>   hourglass to symbolize the passing of time.

From *The House by the Sea: A Journal* by May Sarton:

> WHERE HAS the time gone like sand **pouring** too fast through an
>   hourglass?

From [*Firehorse*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CkAHgetimdsC&pg=PT129&dq=%22sand%20trickling%20through%20an%20hourglass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie2Y7PnNfPAhXEJiYKHfzLCqoQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22sand%20trickling%20through%20an%20hourglass%22&f=false) by D L Wilson:

> This wasn't important work; this was nothing more than sand
>   **trickling** through an hourglass,....

Comment: Those were some pretty neat examples.

Comment: @A.Lau The Ngram viewer (books.google.com/ngrams) lets you search the books that the google has scanned to find how people actually use phrases, tropes, and idioms over time. It's one of my favorite tools.

Answer (score 14):

Sand also ***slips*** through an hourglass.

One of the meanings (mentioned below) of *slip* is *to flow smoothly*.

Also, one of its other definitions is *elapse* which applies to passage of time and nicely fits in the context.

M-W:

> **[slip](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slip)** (slipped, slipping)
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> **1a** :  to move with a smooth sliding motion.
>   **c** :  **elapse**, pass
>
> **4a** :  to slide out of place or away from a support or one's grasp.
>   **b** :  to slide on or down a slippery surface : *slip on the stairs*
>   **c** :  **to flow smoothly**
>
> 7:  sideslip

Comment: Double meaning with 4a as time often *slips* away.

Comment: @NickT, sure yes. I didn't want to mention "slip _away_" as I wanted to leave it to the OP's poetic imagination, but then, you said it.

Answer (score 8):

It all depends on the effect that you want to achieve, and you have given no indication of this in your question. Do you want to suggest time moving slowly, quickly, steadily, or do you want to imply that it is running out?

*Trickle* (as has already been suggested) would indicate time moving slowly. However, *drain* might allude to the one-way flow of time, and *drain inexorably* would really ram it home.

Comment: Any speed is fine, just generally looking for an alternative way to describe sand going through an hourglass.

Answer (score 1):

The word *teem* has a number of [different definitions](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/teem) ranging from 'be abundent' to 'pour out' (the latter leading to the usage "to teem down with rain"). The 'pour out' definition is used extensively in steelmaking to refer to the process of pouring molten steel from the vessel in which it has been made into a mould or the start of a continuous casting plant ([see this reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=77EFCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=teem+steel&source=bl&ots=Y_lFOihbbK&sig=qF_omxWEnpQgHzPQg7tgv5mSCKo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-yq-Kj9fPAhVrKsAKHZmZAVYQ6AEIQDAH#v=onepage&q=teem%20steel&f=false)).

The 'pour out' definition of *teem* might be appropriate for sand running through a glass, particularly if you were trying to express the idea of time running quickly and irrevocably away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emphasize that the time is running out, or slipping away, you might use 'drain'.

Some relevant [definitions from Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drain):

> *intr. v.*
>
> 1b :  to disappear gradually :  *dwindle*
>
> 2 :  to become emptied or freed of liquid by its flowing or dropping : *waiting for the tub to drain*

The sand is acting as a liquid in the hourglass. Obviously the sand is just draining out of the top of the hourglass, not completely out of the whole vessel.

Example:

> Time ran out like sand draining through an hourglass.

Answer (score 0):

*Seeps* has a slightly more poetic feel to me than *drips* has. I really prefer *slips*, as mentioned for its analogous usage with time.

Comment: Please explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about *stream*?

From M-W:

> [*stream*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stream): to move
>   in a steady flow

Example:

> Sand *streamed* from the top to the bottom of the hourglass, presaging
>   my demise.

**Update**: I didn't notice *stream* in any of the answers, which is why I added it, but I notice now that the OP mentioned it in the question. Nevertheless, it's one of the more descriptive and poetic choices, so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly further from the norm, *cascade*.

M-W:

> **[cascade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cascade)** (cascaded, cascading)
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> to fall, pour, or rush in or as if in a cascade
>
> *noun*
>
> 3 : something falling or rushing forth in quantity